# Load youtube video based on current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage based slideshow (index.php), and would like to have a another page (commercial.php) interrupt it every 10 minutes or so, then go back to index.php once the commercial.php page has been up for X minutes.

I'm thinking the way to do it would have the javascript say "if current minutes is divisible by 10, load commercial.php. When commercial.php timer ends, load index.php". I just don't know how to put that into code... :(

Below is a test page I've created just to get the code working, then will move it to the real webpage...

```
<body>

  <div id="time"></div>
  <div class="frame" style="border:1px solid red;width:100%;height:90%;"></div>

  <script>
    function time() {
    $("#time").text(new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds());
    }
    setInterval(time, 1000);
    time();

    //IF STATEMENT TO LOAD VIDEO IN DIV.FRAME?

  </script>

</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took the approach of storing the minutes in a separate variable, and then using the modulus operator on it `mins%10` to see if it equals `0`.

```
function time() {
  var hours = new Date().getHours(),
      mins = new Date().getMinutes(),
      secs = new Date().getSeconds();

  $("#time").text(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);

  if(mins%10 == 0) {
    console.log('sending to commercial.php');
    //location.href = 'commercial.php';
    loadVideo();
  }
}
//setInterval(time, 1000);
time();

function loadVideo(){
    console.log('loading video');
  $('<iframe>', {
   src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?rel=0&autoplay=1',
   width: "560",
   height: "315",
   id:  'myFrame',
   frameborder: 0,
   scrolling: 'no'
   }).appendTo('.frame');
}
```

In the event that it does, you load your video. I wasn't sure if you were redirecting to a new page (which you could do with `location.href` or if you were going to just add it to the page. I took the approach of appending an iframe to the page.

Here's my example https://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/rrgbfa8x/1/

Note that I commented out the interval. You'll want to keep track if a video has already been loaded or not, so for an entire minute, you're not just updating the same video repeatedly. Also, in my fiddle, I added `1==1` to the `if` block. That's just so you can see how the video is loading to your existing page.

As far as how long to display this for, I suppose that depends on where you're loading the video/commercial from. Ideally the video player has an event status that you can tap into. So when the video stops playing, you can detect that and return to the slideshow. [YouTube's Player API has onStateChange](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started). Otherwise, you'll have to know how long each commercial will take and then after 30 seconds (or whatever the length) you return to the slides.

---

As you're looking to have it fade in, you can use jQuery's [`fadeIn` function](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/). In order for this to work when you're adding a new element, you have to hide the element first `display: none;`. In my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/rrgbfa8x/3/ I just set `iframe {display:none;}, then used`.fadeIn(3000)`to fade it in over 3 seconds. To have it fade out, you can look at jQuery's [`fadeOut()`][3](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

```
function loadVideo() {
  console.log('loading video');
  $('<iframe>', {
    src: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?rel=0&autoplay=1',
    width: "560",
    height: "315",
    id: 'myFrame',
    frameborder: 0,
    scrolling: 'no'
  }).appendTo('.frame').fadeIn(3000);
}
```

Comment: this was a great help! took what you gave me and made changes to show various pages. got the youtube api section installed and working too. is there an easy way to make the transitions between index.php and commercial.php fadeIn and out? thanks again!

Comment: No problem. There is a way to do it. You'd need to hide the element that you're adding with CSS, then you can use jquery's `fadeIn()`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple basic approach is as follows:

**index.php**

```
<body>

  <div id="time"></div>
  <div class="frame" style="border:1px solid red;width:100%;height:90%;"></div>

  <script>

    //IF STATEMENT TO LOAD VIDEO IN DIV.FRAME?

    setTimer(function () {
       window.location.href = "commercial.php?parameters...";
    }, 600000); //10 minutes
  </script>

</body>
```

Include any required information in the parameters (such as e.g. info on what to watch or where to start from). Be aware that users can easily intercept and stop client-side timers (but you can't really do much about that).

**commerical.php**

```
Page HTML
<script> 
  setTimer(function () {
     window.location.href = "index.php?parameters...";
  }, X); //Min time in this page?
</script>
```

In your return parameters you could probably re-pass the ones you've got from index which may include information required to resume from where you were. This is probably not the same as your suggestion but it can be seen as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was thinking of doing it this way but I was worried it could bog things down, having a counter go for so long. I plan on trying @EnigmaRN solution, but will give this a go as well. Always good to learn more than one way to do something. Thanks again!